# Internal Server Error on FindItems for Public Folders

Tags: exception, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I've a simple VB.NET application to get all items on a Public Contact Folder. I know that this code works for many years. We upgraded on our OnPremise Exchange 2013 to CU23 for a few month and installed the Hafnium patches (BTW: Our server was not compromised and is not attached directly to the internet).

I think after this upgrade (But I'm not pretty sure) we have the problem that the request "FindItems" on a PublicFolder "Kontakte (Global)" returns an Internal Server Error. Here is the code:

```
Dim objExchangeService As New ExchangeService

objExchangeService.Credentials = objCredentials
objExchangeService.Url = New Uri(strExchangeUrl)


Dim objFolderView As New FolderView(intBatchSize, intFoldersOffset)
Dim objFolders As FindFoldersResults = objExchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, objFolderView)
Dim objGlobalContacts As Folder = objFolders.FirstOrDefault(Function(objFolder) "Kontakte (Global)".Equals(objFolder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))

Dim objView As New ItemView(Int32.MaxValue)
objExchangeService.FindItems(objGlobalContacts.Id, objView) ' Exception here -> Internal Server Error
```

We got this Exception:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Interner Serverfehler. Fehler bei diesem Vorgang.
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ProcessWebException(WebException webException)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, ViewBase view)
```

Has anybody an idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case the InternalURL of the ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory was not preset. That means if I enter "Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory" it returns nothing.

I found the solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/916154/virtual-directory-activesync-exchange-2010-its-there-its-not-there

In my Active Directory there was no object "Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync (Default Web Site)" but in the IIS the website exists. I cannot create a new virtual directory because there exists an orphaned configration.

I did this to remove the orphaned IIS configuration (https://serverfault.com/questions/916154/virtual-directory-activesync-exchange-2010-its-there-its-not-there - Second answer):

```
OK I finally have this one resolved, I want to share the solution in case someone else runs into it. Everything that follows here requires full Admin rights.

Please run from powershell (on the exchange server)

$Site = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync"

and then run

$site

Result:
distinguishedName:
Path: {C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Client Access\Sync}

Next run:

$Site = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root"
$site.Delete("IIsWebVirtualDir","Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync")
$site.SetInfo()

This will remove the phantom virtual directory.

Now run:

iisreset

Now run:

New-activesyncvirtualdirectory -websitename "Default Web Site"

it should recreate the new virtual directory.

Run iisreset again, and edit the internal and external URL's

Then go get yourself a cold one.
```

After these steps I got no errors on the "Apps" Tab and my code works. I think during this problem occurs during the CU update.

Best regards

Rainer

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to just get the last item in the folder eg

```
Dim objView As New ItemView(1)
objExchangeService.FindItems(objGlobalContacts.Id, objView)
```

You shouldn't be doing

```
Dim objView As New ItemView(Int32.MaxValue)
```

as throttling will stop you getting more then 1000 items by default anyways so you should be paging but I would first test just trying to get 1 item. You could also do some testing using the EWSEditor https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases outside of what your code is doing which is even easier then changing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with ItemView(1) and got the same error. I used the EWSEditor but I cannot see any option to get items from the public folders.

In the meanwhile I checked the error log of the EWS folder. I got the exception:

```
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.GlobalServiceUrls.GetInternalUrl[Service](String serverFqdn)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.HttpProxyBackEndHelper.GetBackEndServiceUrlByServer[ServiceType](BackEndServer backEndServer)  
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.BackEndLocator.CallWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`1 actualCall)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.EwsClientHelper.DiscoverEwsUrl(IMailboxInfo mailbox)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.RemotePublicFolderOperations.Execute[T](Boolean writeOperation  CallContext callContext  RemoteExecute`1 executeEWSOperation)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.RemotePublicFolderOperations.GetFolderReplica(CallContext callContext  Byte[] folderIdBytes)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.IdConverter.ServerInfoFromIdHeaderInformation(CallContext callContext  IdHeaderInformation header  Boolean isHierarchyOperations)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ServiceObjectId.InitServerInfo(Boolean isHierarchicalOperation)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.EvaluateMailboxMetrics(List`1 ids  Boolean isHierarchicalOperation)   
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.Submit[T](AsyncCallback hostCallback  Object hostState)    
   bei AsyncInvokeBeginBeginFindItem(Object   Object[]   AsyncCallback   Object )    
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeBegin(Object instance  Object[] inputs  AsyncCallback callback  Object state)   
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)   
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)   
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet);
   FaultInnerException=Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.InternalServerErrorException: Interner Serverfehler. 
   Fehler bei diesem Vorgang. ---> 

Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.VDirConfigurationMissingException: 
   Das virtuelle Clientzugriffsverzeichnis-Objekt mit InternalUrl gestempelt für den -Dienst konnte nicht gefunden werden. Letzter überprüfter Server: EXCHANGE. (MEANS: Could not locate Client Access Virtual Directory object with InternalUrl stamped for service)  
  
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.GlobalServiceUrls.DiscoverUrlsIfNeeded()    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.GlobalServiceUrls.GetInternalUrl[Service](String serverFqdn)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.HttpProxyBackEndHelper.GetBackEndServiceUrlByServer[ServiceType](BackEndServer backEndServer)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.BackEndLocator.CallWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`1 actualCall)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.EwsClientHelper.DiscoverEwsUrl(IMailboxInfo mailbox)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.RemotePublicFolderOperations.Execute[T](Boolean writeOperation  CallContext callContext  RemoteExecute`1 executeEWSOperation)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.RemotePublicFolderOperations.GetFolderReplica(CallContext callContext  Byte[] folderIdBytes)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.IdConverter.ServerInfoFromIdHeaderInformation(CallContext callContext  IdHeaderInformation header  Boolean isHierarchyOperations)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ServiceObjectId.InitServerInfo(Boolean isHierarchicalOperation)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.EvaluateMailboxMetrics(List`1 ids  Boolean isHierarchicalOperation)    
   bei Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.Submit[T](AsyncCallback hostCallback  Object hostState)
```

I think there must be something wrong with the Internal URLs and I checked our URLs with:

```
   Get-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory (No Internal URL set)
   Get-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory (No Internal URL set)
   Get-EcpVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
   Get-MapiVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
   Get-OabVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
   Get-OwaVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
   Get-PowerShellVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
   Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory (Internal URL set)
```

Maybe this error belongs to: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/troubleshoot/dynamics-365/sales/issue-when-adding-to-outlook-error-when-deploying-dynamics-365-app-for-outlook - Because I got the same error. I will check the URLs today or tomorrow evening.